# How to use bigint as getdate()

Tags: sql-server

Basicly i want to insert a periot item on creating new character whcich  expire exactly 7 days after the creating of the character.

Period item table is like that:

```
[id]
  ,[UserGUID]
  ,[CharacterName]
  ,[ItemType]
  ,[ItemCode]
  ,[EffectCategory]
  ,[EffectType1]
  ,[EffectType2]
  ,[Serial]
  ,[Duration]
  ,[BuyDate]
  ,[ExpireDate]
  ,[UsedInfo]
  ,[BuyDateString]
  ,[ExpireDateString]
  ,[SetExpire]
```

and here is the stamnet that i want to use:

```
            DECLARE @memb_guid int
        SELECT @memb_guid = memb_guid FROM MEMB_INFO WHERE memb___id = @AccountID
        INSERT INTO dbo.IGC_PeriodItemInfo(UserGUID,CharacterName,ItemType,ItemCode,EffectCategory,EffectType1,EffectType2,Serial,Duration,BuyDate,ExpireDate,UsedInfo,BuyDateString,ExpireDateString,SetExpire)
        VALUES(@memb_guid, @Name,1,6700,61,6,7,159171,604800,?,?,1,GETDATE(),DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()),0)
```

so where is the "?" sign in the statemant, these types are bigint and i need to use them as getdate() and dateadd(). The Problem is that i dont know how exactly to do it.

Comment: If you want to store datetimes why not make the columns datetimes?  Failing that format to 'yyyyMMdd...' and cast or store as an offset via datediff().

Comment: You can convert a date to a number, and store the number: SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,GETDATE()) But as @AlexK. has asked, why do that if you need them as dates and need to calculate the date diff etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
DECLARE @sdate char(10) = '20/10/2016';
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @sdate, 103);-- 2016-10-20 00:00:00.000
SELECT CONVERT(bigint,CONVERT(datetime, @sdate, 103));  -- 42661
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(bigint,CONVERT(datetime, @sdate, 103)));--2016-10-20 00:00:00.000


CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),DATEDIFF(S,'20380119',GETDATE()))
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,
LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,126),'-',''),':',''),'T',''),14))
```

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+, another option is **Format()**

**Example**

```
Select AsDateTime = GetDate()
      ,AsBigInt   = cast(format(GetDate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssfff') as bigint)
```

**Returns**

```
AsDateTime                AsBigInt
2017-09-11 08:01:38.187   20170911080138187
```

One should note, that Format() has some great functionality, but it not known to be a high performer